# Specifying generic type when accessing a c# dynamic object

Tags: .net, generics, dynamic, c#-4.0

Is it possible to get a generic result from the dynamic object. I'm trying to create a dynamic wrapper around the Json.Net JObject class. It works but when returning an array, I always have to return them as `List<object>`. What I would have preferred would be `List<T>`.

```
dynamic d = new DynamicJson(json);
var result = d.GetValues<string>();
var d = (string[])d.tags;
```

DynamicJson is a custom class. Also, when a call is made with the generic parameter, how is it passed to the dynamic object?

```
public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
   //how do I determine the generic types in this code?
   //can I just do the  casting?
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would assume the answer (iow the type args) is avaialble in `binder`.

Comment: It's almost a year later, but did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nah. In the end I just had to work with List<object>. The new json.net support the dynamic feature so I'm thinking about dropping DynamicJson for the default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, generic parameters never get passed to the `TryGetMember()` or `TryInvokeMember` overrides. The MSDN documentation only shows simple string names getting passed in by the `GetMemberBinder` and `GetInvokeBinder` objects.

The most simple implementation is to actually implement `GetValues<T>()` on the `DynamicJSON` class.

```
public List<T> GetValues<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Called with generic parameter {0}", typeof(T));
    return new List<T>();
}
```

When I ran this simple test, the generic parameter was a .NET `Int32` type:

```
dynamic json = new DynamicJSON();
json.GetValues<int>()
```

If implementing the `GetValues<T>()` method is not feasible for you, you can implement `TryInvokeMember()` to return a method that has `TryConvert()` implemented. When .NET tries to convert the result of `GetValues<int>()` into a `List<int>()`, your overridden `TryConvert()` method will get called with `List<int>()` as the "convert binder type".

```
public class DynamicJSON : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, out Object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "GetValues")
        {
            result = new DynamicValues();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class DynamicValues : DynamicObject
    {
        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out Object result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Converting dynamic values to {0}", binder.Type);

            if (binder.Type == typeof(List<int>))
            {
                result = new List<int>();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic json = new DynamicJSON();
        List<int> values = json.GetValues();
        Console.WriteLine(values.GetType());
    }
}
```